# Копирование файла в буфер обмена (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возможно-ли скопировать файл, например картинку, в буфер обмена?
Пытался сделать по этому ответу - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6064304/10151143 но у меня не получается установить PyQt4.

Comment: а что вы потом хотите делать с ним?

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров выполнить сочетание клавиш CTRL+V

Comment: Ну в смысле это где-то в браузере?

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров не обязательно. Программа, которая принимает изображения через буфер обмена

Answer (score 0):

В общем я решил проблему сам, и мне помог данный код:

```
from io import BytesIO
import win32clipboard
from PIL import Image

def send_to_clipboard(clip_type, data):
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(clip_type, data)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

filepath = 'image.jpg'
image = Image.open(filepath)

output = BytesIO()
image.convert("RGB").save(output, "BMP")
data = output.getvalue()[14:]
output.close()

send_to_clipboard(win32clipboard.CF_DIB, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Установим PyQt5:

```
pip install PyQt5
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

Копируем файлы в буфер обмена (Windows), достаем из буфера обмена и визуализируем:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import * 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        urlsList = ['Ok.png', 'im.png']
        lenUrlsList = len(urlsList)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        # Создайте данные MIME с URL.
        mime_data = QMimeData()
        urls = []
        for url in urlsList:
            urls.append(QUrl.fromLocalFile('{}'.format(url)))
        mime_data.setUrls(urls)

        # Скопируйте данные MIME в буфер обмена.
        clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
        clipboard.setMimeData(mime_data)       

        # Достаем из буфкра обмена
        cm = clipboard.mimeData()
        labelList = [ i for i in range(lenUrlsList)]
        for i, m in enumerate(cm.urls()):
            print(f"m.urls():{m}")
            labelList[i] = QLabel(self)
            labelList[i].setPixmap(QPixmap(m.toLocalFile()))
            layout.addWidget(labelList[i])      


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]